# Port Forwarding Not Working on Mikrotik hap AC

Tags: routing, nat

I have set my MikroTik RouterBoard hap AC as the router instead of my Modem/Router that my ISP gave me.

I'm trying to set port forwarding using a tutorial I've found in google.
That's the configuration of my Port Forwarding:

```
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic
0    ;;; defconf: masquerade
     chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=ether1 log=no log-prefix=""

1    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.1.7 to-ports=8081 protocol=tcp in-interface=ether1 dst-port=8081
```

And That's my ip address configuration:

```
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic
#   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE
0   ;;; defconf
    192.168.1.1/24     192.168.1.0     ether2-master
1 D 100.100.161.43/23  100.100.160.0   ether1
```

I have to say that 100.100.161.43 is the IP the modem gave to my router, but it isn't my ISP IP.

The Port Forwarding isn't working at all. I've tried tcpdump to check if 192.168.1.7 is getting any packets while I'm trying to reach it, but no traffic is being captured.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: When you try to access from outside, do you use 100.100.161.43:8081 ?

Comment: No, I use my public IP.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100.64.0.0/10 is a special IP-range defined in [RFC6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598), commonly known as 'shared address space'. The typical use of this is that ISP's which are running out of IPv4 space assign customers an IP address from this range and use [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) to provide access to the public internet.

The most important reason they use this specific range is that it does not overlap with private IP ranges assigned in [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918), so application layer protocol inspection will be able to distinguish the ISP's NAT from the client's NAT.

So the problem here is that your NAT is placed behind the ISP's NAT. That's why you see another IP when you check your address on a website. You will have to contact your ISP if you need to run publicly accessable services, because at this moment you do not have your own public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

100.100.161.43 is public address. Let's call it Address M. If you are not using Address M as a destination when trying to access from outside, that means public address you are trying to reach (Address R) does not forward your request to Mikrotik (Address M). Either try accessing from outside to Address M, or you need to ask your ISP to forward port on Address R to Address M.
Other than that your Mikrotik configuration looks good.

Comment: 100.100.161.43 is *not* a public address, see RFC6598.

Comment: @MarkoS, if I'm checking what is my IP, I'm getting a different IP address. I'm not sure if the 100 address is open to the world.